# DIrectory automatically Broken in Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: files, directory, ubuntu-budgie

As you can see in the below pictures,Two (Music and Videos) directories are automatically broken.Do anyone know the reason for this and how to fix this. Though both the directories were empty.Can this happen with Filled Directories too ?
I am using Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3 LTS. Thank you.
[image: File SS]

[image: Properties]

Output of ls -ld

```
ls -ld Music Videos

lrwxrwxrwx 1 manish519 manish519 50 Oct 23 19:01 Music -> 
/home/manish519/../../../../../media/storage/Music
lrwxrwxrwx 1 manish519 manish519 51 Oct 23 19:01 Videos -> 
/home/manish519/../../../../../media/storage/Videos
```

Comment: This looks wierd , But anyways you can try creating new directories , And if the problem occur again then we should take an action till now it looks fine

Comment: Please show output from `ls -ld Music Videos` so we can see the real problem.  I suspect it is a broken symlink?  Just `rm` it and `mkdir`  to create it.

Comment: @Algnis. Sure, but if this happens with the filled directories then it would be a problem :(

Comment: @user10489 I have added the output. Kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your Music and Video directories are on external media that is currently unplugged.

You need to decide if you want them to remain on that external media or if you want to recreate them from scratch on your local disk.

Comment: Yes, these directories are on external media but it is not unplugged , I have mounted the external volume. As you can see in above picture the other directories (containing data) are working fine. Why only these two empty directories broke ?

Comment: if your external media is mounted, maybe it isn't on /media/storage as it looked like it was when these links were created?

Comment: The external volume is permanently mounted at /media/storage. Only the directories which were empty broke after few days of mounting ,rest of the directories are working fine. What can be the reason for this ?

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information to determine what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for that , I do not know much abt linux as I'm new into this. Can you please specify what information do u need so I can provide you with that. Thank you !